# SQL convert string in the form of yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ssZ to datetime

Tags: sql, date, hadoop, hive, timestamp

I have a variable in the format of string, such as 2019-11-25T14:22:56.529Z. And I need to extract the date part of this string variable and extract all records with the latest date.

```
ID   time (in string format, not a timestamp yet)
-------------------------------
1    2019-11-25T15:20:56.539Z
2    2019-11-25T04:23:56.522Z
3    2019-11-25T11:11:54.509Z
4    2019-12-25T10:22:36.129Z
5    2019-12-25T09:22:29.349Z
6    2019-12-25T08:22:56.209Z
```

I want this output:

```
ID   time
---------------
4    2019-12-25
5    2019-12-25
6    2019-12-25
```

In general, I would also like to know how to convert this type of string variable to date format for future sorting by datetime. Thank you!

Comment: @marc_s it included date and time ? But for the output I only wanted date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do achieve it like below :

```
SELECT ID, FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(time, "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"),"yyyy-MM-dd") as time
FROM yourtable
```

Comment: Hi, this does not work, all date+time values returned as null..

Comment: try execute small set like SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2020-01-17T00:00:04.226Z', "yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss.SSS'Z'" ); does it works ?

Comment: That worked, but the code does not work on the dataset.

Comment: The string variable has type(DB) string and type(JDBC) as varchar.

Comment: how about SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(1579292138113, ,"yyyy-MM-dd")

Comment: returned as 52015-10-11

Comment: SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(1579292138113 DIV 1000, "yyyy-MM-dd") this ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206174/discussion-between-lydias-and-ronak-dhoot).

Comment: Hi Ronak, just wondering, if I want to add the rest of the timestamp such as h, m and s to the conversion, how should I do that? @RonakDhoot

Answer (score 3):

Just use the substring function for this

```
select substr(time,1,10) as date from tablename;
```

**Update**
This would convert it back to date and you can do your sorting

```
select cast(substr(time,1,10) as date) as date from tablename;
```

Comment: I'm aware of I can use substr, but how do I convert it to a time? I need to sort dataset by time and range of date/time later on.

Comment: This also worked! I gave accepted @RonakDhoot  for his efforts XD...

Comment: @StandinWolf  if I want to include h, m and second to the conversion, how should I do that?